# Negative infinity produced when computing log-likelihood in Poisson Regression R

Tags: poisson-regression, likelihood

I am trying to compute the log-likelihood in a Poisson regression in R.
However, my computation produces negative infinity values for some observations.
This is my code:

```
freq*exposure * log(lambda)- lambda - log(factorial(freq*exposure))
```

the $-\infty$ occurs in the `factorial(freq*exposure)` portion when the frequency and exposure are too large.

Does anyone know how to get around this? When I discretize my data into smaller bins the issue disappears, however, I get a worse fit.

## UPDATE

The error occurs when I use these observations:

```
exposure = 2.994500e+03
frequency = 0.13224244
exposure*frequency = 396
```

## UPDATE2

Based on @StupidWolf's suggestion I changed the `log(factorial(freq*exposure))` in the log-likelihood to:

```
freq*exposure * log(lambda)- lambda - lfactorial(freq*exposure)
```

this solved the issue.

Comment: can you provide the values that give this error? one option is to use lfactorial()

Comment: @StupidWolf I have included the values. That sounds like a good idea. I should have thought of that

Comment: Is there are a reason for not using `dpois(freq*exposure, lambda, log=TRUE)`?

Comment: @MarG see GordonSmyth's comments. I also wanted to ask why you don't want to use logLik() since it's a poisson regression

Comment: @GordonSmyth I just feel like I get a better understanding if I do computations as "manually" as possible.

Comment: @StupidWolf see my previous answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the world of numerical overflow!

Using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=396%21) I calculated $396! > 10^{859}$ i.e. a $1$ with  $859$ zeros trailing behind it. The biggest number your computer can handle will be around $10^{308}$ (probably). [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507920/largest-possible-values-in-r). What's happened in your code is the computer has tried to compute `factorial(exposure*frequency)` and rounded this up to $+ \infty$, taking the negative log of this will return $-\infty$.

Using a command like `lfactorial` will circumvent this issue. A factorial is a product and a log of products is just a sum. `lfactorial` will compute the log factorial as

$$\texttt{lfactorial}(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log(i)$$ which is much more ''numerically stable'' than computing
$$\texttt{log(factorial(n))} = \log \left\{ 1\times2\times\cdots\times n\right\}$$